# Mysql to PDO code conversion

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am fairly new to the PHP scene, and I am trying to solve a bug in a friend's website. However, I have encountered a basic problem when testing it on localhost.

Essentially, the website is old and uses deprecated mysql command. Although mysql queries are spread out through the entire code, I only need to modify a couple of files where the bug is located.

However, in the config.inc file which is used in all php files, the following lines are included :

```
    define("ML",mysql_connect("localhost:/tmp/aaaaa.sock","dbocccccccc","pass"),true);
    define ("DB",mysql_select_db("dbcccccccc"));
```

I am getting a fatal error ad PDOException when converting this to PDO :

```
    define("ML", new PDO('mysql:host=localhost/tmp/aaaaa.sock;dbname = dbcccccccc', 'dbocccccccc','pass'), true);
```

I'm guessing my syntax is incorrect in some way or another, yet when I try a simple direct connect to the database (same as above, but without the define), I get the following error :

```
Error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Acces denied for user 'dbocccccccc'@'@localhost' (password: YES)
```

The double @ is what bugs me here. The input is the same (changed password and database name for privacy, but that's all) as the one found in the website sources.

So, what is the issue ? What have I got wrong here ?

Comment: you can't define constants like that. a `define()'d` constant can only have a scalar value. a PDO object is **NOT** a scalar. In other words, you code is impossible to convert without a total re-write

Comment: @MarcB it is also possible to define ressources, such as a PDO object? http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php: `It is possible to define resource constants, however it is not recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior. `  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: moreover, the error is about the connection problem, not a illegal conversion to scalar (or I don't know how php would name that)

Comment: Is there no minor workaround that would enable one to do this ? I'm not familiar at all with include files but this seems rather surprising.  Alternately, if I could get mysql to show up properly, deprecated though it might be, I could do the testing I wish to do. I only need to solve this bug before working on a complete redesign.

Thanks for the answers, by the way, everyone.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: a resource constant is just an int. e.g. `FILE_UPLOAD_ERR_OK` is just another way of saying `0`, but that's still just an int. a PDO object is a living/breathing thing, not a dead number. And like it says, "may cause unpredictable behavior". Good luck debugging your system if you try this and get heisenbugs

Comment: I'd agree that using `define()` is an extremely heavy-handed approach here. Globals are almost always trouble.

Comment: compared to the (not so much) trouble of passing database objects to methods and functions, a global db handler does seem like a lot of pain...

Answer (score 1):

You could try specifying `unix_socket=/tmp/aaaa.sock` instead of `host=`.

The [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) describes the options in more detail.

Comment: from the doc: `unix_socket: The MySQL Unix socket (shouldn't be used with host or port).` whereas op is trying to use a socket with host

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier It's an either/or thing. Specify `host` and an optional `port`, or use the `unix_socket` approach. That configuration string implies it needs a socket. The MySQL access-control system treats local connections over socket differently from IP ones, even those made to `localhost`.

Comment: Adding the ARRAY part yields an unknown network error. Changing to unix_socket and/or removing the .sock extension yields the same connection error as the one I first mentioned.

Comment: You shouldn't be removing the `.sock` extension. You should be specifying the actual full path to the socket. Does `ls -l /tmp/aaaaa.sock` or whatever it's called show a socket file?

Comment: I'm on windows, using Wampserver. I have putty, but I'm not sure how exactly I can do that check you want me to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use the socket method on Windows. You probably want to specify the `host` without the meaningless path on the end. Try connecting with the `mysql` command-line tool to see what options work.

Comment: Still unsure about what to type. I'm unused to command lines.

Comment: First of all you need to determine how you're supposed to connect to your server and verify that it's working as you think it is. The `mysql` command-line tool can do the job, as can the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) when configured correctly. When you know what it's supposed to be, getting the correct PDO initialization string is going to be a lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

Per the Php ManPage...

```
new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'user', 'xxx', array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
```